# SORT PER PROFIT IN EACH MARKETS

Tags: google-sheets

I am facing an issue that I want to sort data according to different market places. A sample file is attached here. in that, each product has different profits in each market. I want to sort from the highest profit to the lowest profit. but I don't know how to. maybe with a drop-down list, when I select the US, it must show the product with the highest profit on top. same as each market. when I select France, products come in order from high profit to low. Hope you understand what I need.

Here is the sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXNOUSaU-L9Ah7wJIT768WkT7UgXeDyt9pTgoyvn6S0/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 3):

You can always create a filter in your table, to do so, you need to:

- select your table
- click the filter button on the top:
  [image]
- click on the header and `sort by Z -> A`

Comment: @naibais.. my friend pls take a look to my latest question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170737/find-status-of-a-product-if-it-is-noted-any-column-in-an-unique-column